# how to make repo status appear in posh git (oh-my-posh)

Tags: powershell, posh-git, oh-my-posh

so basically i want the repository status to be shown and not hidden like this example :

[image]

and my terminal without theme shows the repo status but when i apply a theme the numbers (repo status ) disapear like yo see in this pic :

[image]

so any fix to that prob ??

Answer (score 0):

The theme you have chosen does not include the git add/modified/deleted/untracked counts. For example `paradox.omp.json` does not include them. To include these counts, you can either:

1. Choose a theme which does include the full git information, such as [peru](https://github.com/JanDeDobbeleer/oh-my-posh/blob/main/themes/peru.omp.json)

or

2. Edit your oh-my-posh theme file (e.g. `paradox.omp.json`) to include the git counts. Find the `git` segment, and add the following lines into the properties section:

```json
"fetch_status": true,
"template": "{{ .HEAD }} {{ .BranchStatus }}{{ if .Working.Changed }} \uF044 {{ .Working.String }}{{ end }}{{ if and (.Staging.Changed) (.Working.Changed) }} |{{ end }}{{ if .Staging.Changed }} \uF046 {{ .Staging.String }}{{ end }}{{ if gt .StashCount 0}} \uF692 {{ .StashCount }}{{ end }}{{ if gt .WorktreeCount 0}} \uf1bb {{ .WorktreeCount }}{{ end }}"
```